# How to apply a hbase patch?

Tags: hbase, patch, thrift

I want to use the regex with RowFilter  when i  select data from hbase using php by `thrift0.92.`But it seems that `scannerOpenWithScan` cannot execute when `TScan` initilized by an RowFilter.
I want to apply a hbase patch from [HBASE-4176](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-4176).
But I do not know how to patch it and if i should rebuild my hbase.

Comment: The issue you mentioned is marked as fixed in HBase 0.92.0. Installing HBase version >= 0.92.0 will almost certainly be easier than applying a patch to an older version.

Comment: @kostya Thanks for your help.I've installed HBase 1.0.0.But after my trial I  found a new interesting problem.When I use a rowfilter like this: <code>$flt="RowFilter(=,'regexstring:^admin$')";
$s=new \Hbase\TScan(array("startRow"=>"admin","stopRow"=>"admio","filterString"=>$flt));</code> ,it works.But if the <code>TScan</code> has no startRow or stopRow but has filterString, it does not work.